# Evaluating trigonometric functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, precision

Is there a way in Haskell to specify the precision (say r bits) for the numerical calculation of trigonometric functions?

Comment: Stackoverflow is **not** a library/package/software/tutorial recommendation site. Such questions are *off topic*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as Haskell goes, all trigonometric functions in specified in the language (and that are in `base` --- `sin`, `cos`, etc.) are overloaded/polymorphic using typeclasses, so every type gets to implement a one-time-implemented `sin`, `cos`, etc.

So `Float` gets to implement `sin`, `cos`, and `Double` gets to implement it, etc.

So customizing the precision of `sin` might be just a matter of finding a type somewhere that fits the precision you need.  Every type gets to implement its own `sin`, so they're free to give whatever precision they want.

You can also just write your own versions of `sin` and `cos` that "round" or truncate precision in the way you want, and name it `sin'` or `cos'` or something like that too :)

```
sin' x = (/100) . realToFrac . round . (*100) . sin
```

maybe, for instance

Comment: If I wanted to 400 bits of precision using the above function, would it be able to give me that? Also would it be fast enough?

Comment: Every type implements its own `sin`/`cos`.  So you need to find a type that calculates it with 400 bits of precision.  Neither `Float` nor `Double` do this, so you might want to hunt around/search for high-precision real number types :)

Remember it's the types that define their precision.  `sin`/`cos`/etc. are overloaded and definable by every time.  So find a high precision type and chances are it'll have a high precision sin/cos.

Comment: I think I get your point. But obviously Haskell does not come equipped with an arbitrary precision Fractional type which has sin defined for it (since the sine function would be restricted to some type class). So does that mean I have to construct it?

Comment: You can construct it, or you can search for a package/library somewhere that provides it